# Create new columns in r based on year column

Tags: r

Original file looks like:

| Year | Student_Group | N_Tests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | White | 9 |
| 2020 | Black | 9 |
| 2020 | Hispanic | 8 |
| 2021 | White | 12 |
| 2021 | Black | 14 |
| 2021 | Hispanic | 15 |
| 2022 | White | 13 |
| 2022 | Black | 14 |
| 2022 | Hispanic | 14 |

I want to create new columns based on the year and get rid of the first column so it should look like:

| Student_Group | 2020_N_Tests | 2021_N_Tests | 2022_N_Tests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 9 | 12 | 13 |
| Black | 9 | 14 | 14 |
| Hispanic | 8 | 15 | 14 |

Not sure where to start with this in r, any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the `pivot_wider`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(Year=paste0(Year,'_N_Tests')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols =  Student_Group, names_from = Year, values_from = N_Tests)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Student_Group `2020_N_Tests` `2021_N_Tests` `2022_N_Tests`
  <chr>                  <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 White                      9             12             13
2 Black                      9             14             14
3 Hispanic                   8             15             14
```